Mark 13:32: If only the Father knows the Day and the Hour, then how can Jesus be God?
Mark 13:32 ESV says,

“But concerning that day or that hour, no one knows, not even the
angels in heaven, nor the Son, but the Father only."

Jesus, along with the angels, do not know the Day or the Hour. Only God the Father knows it. Jesus and the angels share ignorance of it except God.
Does this point to Jesus being an angel and not God?

The list is quite long. And the question keeps coming up . . . . . . .

The "lack" of knowledge is partial, only the day and hour are not known. There is no basis for saying there is a complete lack of knowledge,  that is, the year and month are known. The question is why the exact moment is known by the Father only. There are several reasons why the Father who remained in heaven while the Son was sent, died, and spent 3 days and 3 nights in the heart of the earth might know day and hour differently. But the difference doesn't "change" the calendar.

@RevelationLad - only the Father knows the exact moment, because only the Father is God and knows all things as He plans then. Jesus does now do his own will, but the will of Him who sent him (which was God his Father).

Perhaps you're ignoring the reality and consequences of becoming human relative to measuring time from heaven. If the Father told you the hour and day was September 1, 2024 at 9:00AM. Would you know the hour and day?

@RevelationLad, even the angels do not know it, and they are not humans!

You are bring evasive because you know having the exact date and exact hour isn't enough to know when it will happen.

@RevelationLad - Why does Jesus get tempted in the desert when God cannot be tempted? Why does Jesus say that nobody is good but his Father who is in heaven?

You are bring evasive because you know having the exact date and exact hour isn't enough to know when it will happen. This is typical of the "gotcha" question. When you get an answer that points out the deficiency in your doctrine, you refuse to engage with your own question. Instead you move to a different "gotcha" question. You're not interested in an answer.

Equating two entities based on one shared limitation:
Firstly, understand that categorization is based on defining characteristics that determine membership in a particular group or class. A shared limitation does not necessarily define a category. For example, not knowing a specific piece of information could apply to many categories (humans, animals, machines, inanimate objects, etc.). To equate two entities based on a shared limitation, the limitation must be a defining characteristic of their category.
Logical analysis:
If we choose, in this case, to categorize entities based on knowledge, we must consider all aspects of their knowledge, not just a single limitation. The shared limitation (not knowing the Day or the Hour) is certainly not a defining characteristic that determines the category of an entity (whether it is an angel, a human, an inanimate object, or a divine being).
So, equating Jesus with angels solely based on a shared limitation of knowledge is a very incomplete comparison. It ignores characteristics that actually define their respective categories.

We then must ask: is there scripture that might explain why they share this limitation? The answer is, yes.

Philippians 2:6-7 - who, as He already existed in the form of God, did not consider equality with God something to be grasped, 7 but emptied Himself by taking the form of a bond-servant and being born in the likeness of men.

However, for God, categorization would include characteristics such as omnipotence (unlimited power), omniscience (unlimited knowledge), and omnipresence (universal presence). These attributes are considered essential and intrinsic to the nature of a God. The question then arises: can a divine being somehow lack one of these attributes and still be considered divine?

The doctrine of kenosis or self-emptying:

This says that Jesus, in his incarnation, voluntarily limited his divine prerogatives, including his knowledge, to fully experience human life and fulfill his mission of redemption.

The kenosis is the act of Christ taking on a human nature with all of
its limitations, except with no sin. (Gotquestions)

According to Bibleref:

Part of being emptied means Jesus abdicated His rights to manifest the
full nature of deity, what theologians call the kenosis. That doesn't
mean that Jesus was ever not-God. It's more like part of His deity was
in sleep mode. He knew what God intended Him to know (John 15:15).

Conclusion: Jesus operated within the limitations of humanity, which included not knowing the day or hour.

Are you implying that before and after Jesus was a human, that he does know the Day and the Hour, but not while he was a human?

He voluntarily did not access certain divine knowledge during his earthly life. The idea is that Jesus, in his pre-incarnate state (before becoming human) and in his glorified state (after resurrection and ascension), possesses full divine knowledge, which would include knowing the Day and the Hour. However, during his time on earth as a human, he voluntarily limited his divine attributes, including certain aspects of his knowledge, to fully experience humanity. This self-limitation is a temporary state that was specific to his earthly ministry.

Jason_, That seems like a cop out answer to me.

I understand that the explanation might seem unsatisfying. It’s a common reaction to God and complex theological concepts that are difficult to fully comprehend within our human experience.  I am not God; I do not know all the mysteries of God. But I can analyze the scriptures. I simply offer this as an answer that has examined the scriptures.

Jason, Jesus doesn't know the Day or the Hour because the Father is the one who has appointed the times and the seasons and the events. Good knows when Christ can get his bride, like in Jewish culture. Jesus is not God, but the Son of God. His bride is the Church.

I understand you to be non-trinitarian. However, I see it as a beautiful depiction of God as a relationship of love and unity. It portrays God as one essence in three persons: Father, Son, and Holy Spirit. This suggests that at the very heart of the universe is a community bound by love. You need more than one to have community and more than one to love. This makes it a model for human relationships. Unity without uniformity and diversity without division. It means that God is inherently relational, and love is not just an attribute but the essence of His being.
